# Python Pandas Pivot Table Count Occurrences without dummy column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Whats the most elegant way to pivot a dataframe and getting to counts from the following example:

```
id  type
1   A
1   A
1   B
2   A
1   B
```

to get a wide format df looking like this

```
id   A    B
1    2    1
2    1    1
```

At the moment I am going with creating a seperate column and then using aggfunc=sum

```
df.loc[:,"count"] = 1
df.pivot_table(index="id", columns="type", values="count", aggfunc='sum')
```

which works fine.

Using:

```
df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='type', aggfunc='count')
```

returns not the expected result giving me a df with 0 columns and only the ids in its rows.

What am I doing wrong in the second approach and is there a more elegant way instead of creating a seperate column containing only 1s?

Comment: `crosstab` is indeed the standard pandas way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['type'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am wondering if crosstab is really an efficient solution cause i already have a dataframe while crosstab creates a new dataframe not reshaping the existing one according to the docs? I would expect giving a count aggregation to pivot_tables would yield the same results

Comment: @J-H 
Your comments are difficult to understand, and the answer to your question(elegant count way instead of creating a column) is `crosstab`. **If your comments are important, include them in the main text and do not ask the question again after receiving the answer.**